# How to fix this code and make my own POS-tagger? (PYTHON)

Tags: python, nlp, pos-tagger

My program need to read a file with sentences and produce an output like that:

input: Ixé Maria.
output: Ixé\PRON Maria\N-PR.

Until now, I wrote this, but the outfile gives me an empty textfile. (please, give me suggestions):

```py
infile = open('corpus_test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
outfile = open('tag_test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

dicionario = {'mimbira': 'N',
             'anama-itá': 'N-PL',
             'Maria': 'N-PR',
             'sumuara-kunhã': 'N-FEM',
             'sumuara-kunhã-itá': 'N-FEM-PL',
             'sapukaia-apigaua': 'N-MASC',
             'sapukaia-apigaua-itá': 'N-MASC-PL',
             'nhaã': 'DEM',
             'nhaã-itá': 'DEM-PL',
             'ne': 'POS',
             'mukuĩ': 'NUM',
             'muíri': 'QUANT',
             'iepé': 'INDF',
             'pirasua': 'A1',
             'pusé': 'A2',
             'ixé': 'PRON1',
             'se': 'PRON2',
             '. ;': 'PUNCT'
             }

np_words = dicionario.keys()
np_tags = dicionario.values()

for line in infile.splitlines():
   list_of_words = line.split()
   if np_words in list_of_words:
       tag_word = list_of_words.index(np_words)+1
       word_tagged = list_of_words.insert(tag_word, f'\{np_tags}') 
       word_tagged = " ".join(word_tagged)
       print(word_tagged, file=outfile)

outfile.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and explain *what the issue is* with the code - "it doesn't work" doesn't help us.

Comment: Thank you, Karl. I just edited this part

Comment: print it to the screen also ... if it prints to the screen and not the file that would be strange

Comment: thank you, Joran, but even when I print to the screen it doesn't show me anything but "Process finished with exit code 0" and produces the empty text file...

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `if np_words in list_of_words:` to do?

Comment: @DominickMaia What language is this btw?

Comment: Backslash as the POS separator is unusual. It would probably be a good idea to use the same output format as other POS taggers so you don't have to develop a separate parser for your own ad-hoc output format.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel if there's any key from the dictionary in the infile, the algorithm have to print this key in the context sentence followed by its value, which is also the tag I want

Comment: @fzzylogic Nheengatu :)

Comment: thank you @tripleee! I will try this

Comment: This language looks vaguely agglutinative, like you could derive individual tags from separate morphemes (by quick glance, in many cases simply by splitting on dash). Maybe try a morphology-based approach rather than trying to list every word form in a long list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting simply with NLP makes it easier to understand and also to appreciate the more advanced systems.

This gives what you're looking for:

```
# Use 'with' so that the file is automatically closed when the 'with' ends.
with open('corpus_test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # splitlines is not a method, readlines is.
    # infile will contain a list, where each item is a line.
    # e.g. infile[0] = line 1.
    infile = f.readlines()

dicionario = {
    'Maria': 'N-PR',
    'ixé': 'PRON1',
}

# Make a list to hold the new lines
outlines = []

for line in infile:
    list_of_words = line.split()
    
    new_line = ''
    # 'if np_words in list_of_words' is asking too much of Python.
    for word in list_of_words:
        # todo: Dictionaries are case-sensitive, so ixé is different to Ixé.
        if word in dicionario:
            new_line += word + '\\' + dicionario[word] + ' '
        else:
            new_line += word + ' '

    # Append the completed new line to the list and add a carriage return.
    outlines.append(new_line.strip() + '\n')

with open('tag_test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.writelines(outlines)
```

Comment: Amazing!!! Thank you very much, sir! And thank you for the comments and the explanations. That's exactly what I needed. God bless you